# .tpl php template engine development

Tags: php

I have a very basic php template engine up and running using .tpl. Is it possible to use if statements within your .tpl file? I want to detect if a php module is required. In php I would use:

```
<?php
if($news)
{
    include_once(modules/news.php);
}
?>
```

In my .tpl file I'm simply using [news]. It would be great if I could just use:

```
if[news]
```

in my .tpl file.

Apologies if this seems really basic. I'm new to this environment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hard to say without more context of how the templates are constructed.

Comment: Is this a well-known templating engine? It would help if you tell us about it